# Issue with nodejs forever module

Tags: node.js, shell, forever

I have forever module installed on ubuntu 14.10 in a digital ocean droplet. Now when i try to add a script or list with forever command it just takes to prompt. There is no output. Issuing a command : forever start app.js simply takes me the prompt and the script isn't started as i check. I have installed forever as global. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the script terminate prematurely _without_ the use of `forever`; does it work as intended? You can also use the `-l` switch in `forever` to write to a log file.

Comment: I tried keep running using nodejs and it works without any issue. I am using expressjs and listens to 80 port. Its only when using forever. Where is the log location?

Comment: the log location is wherever you specify, e.g. `forever -l ./app.log start app.js`, see the docs: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: does `~/.forever/config.json` exist?

Comment: No ~/.forever/config.json does not exists...